# web3 remix cannot deploy contract

Tags: web3js, remix, contract-deployment, contract-debugging

I have a problem when deploying smart contracts on remix.
When I click create, I can see that transactions are passing through, from the blockchain explorer. I clicked multiple times, and this is the result.

[image: https://imgur.com/a/s6uiqsG]

However, I am getting the below 'error' and the contract does not seem to be deploying. I have tried different contracts and changing browser, to no avail.

[image: https://imgur.com/7W5mBuc]

I am connecting to my node via web3 provider. I can see my wallets

[image]

I am adding a sample smart contract:

```
  contract test{

    int _multiplier;

    function test (int multiplier){
        _multiplier = multiplier;
    }

    function multiply (int val) returns (int d){
        return val * _multiplier;
    }

}
```

When deploying the smart contract, i can see it in geth.

[image]

then i get the error mentioned above in remix.

Comment: Where are you deploying your contract? ie mainnet or private testnet.  Did you try to deploy in the "Javascript VM"? There are several causes that might prevent your contract to deploy: constructor causes an error, gas allowed is not enough. If you show us your source we can inspect the constructor for common errors.

Comment: this is a private blockchain, i tried to deploy on VM 3 contracts, all succeeded. web3 fails

Comment: Does your private tesnet has a block gas limit large enough to deploy your contracts? Can you show us the transaction receipt of the failed deployment? we cannot infer much from the error message you show here. What version of the solidity compiler are you using? Does your private network enabled byzantinum opcodes? Since solc v0.4.22 the compiler generates bytecode with byzantinum opcodes if your private testnet doesn't have them enabled your contract will fail.

Comment: In the genesis I have :  "difficulty": "0x4000",
    "gasLimit": "0x8000000" . Please excuse my ignorance,  but can you enlighten me more with the transaction receipt. I tried to get info from remix but couldnt. i managed to get a transaction receipt working with nethereum

Comment: Remix will show the receipt formatted when you click on the down arrow of the transaction. Can you try compiling with an older version of solidity before v0.4.22 to see if that work?

Comment: i tried doing as you said, and i took down to 0.4.21. Nothing, i attached the recpt in the original question. thx.

Comment: The receipt doesn't have a 'status' field so I believe your are working with a pre byzantinum chain, see this https://medium.com/@chris_77367/explaining-unexpected-reverts-starting-with-solidity-0-4-22-3ada6e82308c. My guess is the problem is with byzantinum opcodes but without seeing your code is hard to say it definitively, try with an older compiler, or try to deploy to a testnet with byzantinum opcodes enabled.

Comment: I tried with Solidity version
Current version:0.4.17+commit.bdeb9e52.Emscripten.clang. Nothing happened. I uploaded above the smart contract.

Comment: did you manage to resolve it?